# Setar uma imagem

Tags: wpf

Estou tentando setar uma imagem, mas não estou conseguindo. Parece que o WPF não consegue encontrar o caminho da imagem. Por quê isso acontece?

```
<Image  Width="60"
        Height="60"
        Stretch="Fill"
        Source="\Images\Tiles\clientes.png" />
```

Comment: Pode me mostrar um screenshot da sua solution explorer apontando para a imagem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Definindo imagem pelo XAML

Você está utilizando as barras ao contrário. O correto seria:

```
<Image  
    Width="60"
    Height="60"
    Stretch="Fill"
    Source="/Images/Tiles/clientes.png" />
```

É possível também criar um `Resource` para as imagens e depois utilizá-las como um `StaticResource`.

Dentro da tag `ResourceDictionary` do arquivo `App.xaml` adicione:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="ImagemCliente" UriSource="/Images/Tiles/clientes.png" />
```

E na sua imagem use dessa forma:

```
<Image  
    Width="60"
    Height="60"
    Stretch="Fill"
    Source="{StaticResource ImagemCliente}" />
```

Dessa forma o código do seu layout fica mais limpo e se for usar a imagem em mais de um lugar por exemplo, quando quiser modificá-la, você terá que alterar em apenas um local.

### Definindo imagem através de Binding

Crie uma propriedade do tipo `ImageSource` na sua classe, que será usada para guardar a imagem desejada. Assumindo que a propriedade utilizada seja `Caminho`, então a definição da imagem na propriedade se daria da seguinte forma:

```
seuObjeto.Caminho = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Tiles/clientes.png"))
```

E o `binding` pelo **XAML**:

```
<Image  
    Width="60"
    Height="60"
    Stretch="Fill"
    Source="{Binding Caminho}" />
```

Não sei como você definiu a estrutura de `binding` no seu projeto, então apenas coloquei a propriedade que deverá ser feita o binding. Dependendo da sua arquitetura, o `binding` pode ser diferente, mas a ideia é a mesma.

### .NET 4.5

Se você estiver utilizando .NET 4.5 e os caminhos informados anteriormente não funcionarem, você terá que utilizar o caminho completo da imagem. Isso se deve ao fato de que a Microsoft fez modificações significativas nessa versão do .NET e "estragou" algumas coisas.

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Images/Tiles/clientes.png">
```

Comment: Mas e seu passar os caminhos através de uma propriedade (String Caminho) e fazer um um Binding, como eu faria?

Comment: Editei a resposta e adicionei o que deseja.

Answer (score 1):

Tive problemas com um projeto meu e realmente demorei para achar a solução, mas o que resolveu pra mim foi colocar o Source da imagem desta forma:

```
<Image  Width="60"
        Height="60"
        Stretch="Fill"
        Source="/Nome.Do.Projeto;component/Images/Tiles/clientes.png"/>
```

Onde **Nome.Do.Projeto** é o namespace do projeto onde a imagem se encontra.

Espero ter ajudado.